# Scala groupby key sum value over a Seq of (key, value) while maintaining Order

Tags: scala, collections

I am trying to resolve a problem with grouping and summing over scala tuples and maintaining the order of keys.

Say,

```
val arrayTuples = Array((A, 38) , (B, 150), (B, 250), (B, 890), (D, 600), (C, 515))
```

to

```
Map(A -> 38, B -> 1290, D -> 600, C -> 515)
```

Doing:

```
val aMap = arrayTuples .groupBy(_._1)
```

seems to mess with the ordering. Help appreciated.

EDIT: Maintain Ordering of first encountered.

Comment: Say you had an `Array(B,A,C,B)`. What is the order you want to preserve? Order of first encountered: `B,B,A,C`, or order of last encountered: `A,C,B,B`?

Comment: Order of first encountered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `ListMap` to preserve order, but if you want the left-to-right order-as-encountered, as requested in the comments, some extra steps are needed.

```
//note the new order of elements
val arrayTuples =
  Array(('A', 38), ('B', 150), ('D', 600), ('B', 250), ('C', 515), ('B', 890))

import collection.immutable.ListMap

arrayTuples.foldRight(ListMap[Char,Int]()) {
  case ((c,n), lm) => lm.updated(c , lm.getOrElse(c, 0)+n)
}.foldRight(ListMap[Char,Int]()){case (elem,lm) => lm+elem}
//res0: ListMap[Char,Int] = ListMap(A -> 38, B -> 1290, D -> 600, C -> 515)
```

Because `ListMap` preserves the order of last-enountered, which in this case would move the `B` entry to the end, I decided to `foldRight`, which moves the `A` entry to the end, and then `foldRight` again to reverse the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can get an insertion ordered map like this:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

val tuples = List(("A", 38) , ("B", 150), ("B", 250), ("B", 890), ("C", 515), ("D", 600))

val initMap = ListMap.empty[String, List[(String, Int)]].withDefaultValue(List.empty)

val aMap = tuples.foldLeft(initMap) { case (acc, (k, v)) =>
  val newList = (k -> v) :: acc(k)
  acc + (k -> newList)
}

println(aMap) // Map(A -> List((A,38)), B -> List((B,890), (B,250), (B,150)), C -> List((C,515)), D -> List((D,600)))
```

Answer (score 2):

By default the scala Map is an unsorted collection, but you can use [ListMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html):

```
val summedTuples = arrayTuples
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
  .toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
// ArrayBuffer((A,38), (B,1290), (C,515), (D,600))

ListMap(summedTuples: _*)
// Map(A -> 38, B -> 1290, C -> 515, D -> 600)
```

**EDIT**: So upon re-reading the question along with the clarifications on 'first-encountered' ordering, rather than just remove my answer I adapted it slightly below. I still prefer the accepted answer above but can't hurt to have an alternative:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

val arrayTuples = Array(("A", 38) , ("B", 150), ("B", 250), ("B", 890), ("D", 600), ("C", 515))

val summedTuples = arrayTuples
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
  .toSeq.sortBy(k => arrayTuples.indexWhere(_._1 == k._1)) // yes, I'm sorting by the original order...

ListMap(summedTuples : _*) // Map(A -> 38, B -> 1290, D -> 600, C -> 515)
```